# How do I get a custom image in my tab bar? Window mode project, NOT TAB BAR!

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, tabbar

I've looked everywhere for a proper tutorial on how you change your tab bar to a custom image. Every tutorial out there uses a tab bar application, not window mode as I do! So, how do I change the image? Got a 49x49 img ready to use.

Used this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBvpM1-i3EM
It did'nt work 'cause I did'nt have a tab bar application.

Please, help!

Comment: Are you looking for how to change the icons of tabs to custom images, or for how to change the appearance of the tab bar itself?

Comment: Also, note that traversing a private view hierarchy and changing views within a UITabBar, like is done in that tutorial, is highly discouraged.  This may cause your application to break in future OS releases of Apple changes the internal view structure of these elements.

Comment: Yeah, but what should I do then? I really need to change the appearance of the tab bar!

Comment: In general, the approach seems to be to create a custom view to serve this purpose: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778466/how-to-customize-the-appearance-of-a-tab-bar